# Свой publicPath для каждой точки входа (webpack)

Tags: webpack

*webpack 4.29.3*

есть несколько точек входа, пример:

```
entry: {
    common: '/common/index.js',
    mobile: '/common/mobile.js',
    site: '/site/common/js/site.js',
    ...
}
```

И каждая точка входа должна иметь свой **output.publicPath**, **output.path**

Создавать n конфигов для каждой точки входа такое себе решение, потому что всё остальное (плагины, настройки конфигов однотипны)

Есть ли какое то решение данной проблемы ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением данной проблемы может быть использование нескольких конфигураций либо сеттинг нужной переменной прямо в рантайме:

```
// webpack.config.js
const common = {
  entry: './common/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'common.js',
    publicPath: 'publicPath for common'
  }
};

const mobile = {
  entry: './common/mobile.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'mobile.js',
    publicPath: 'publicPath for mobile'
  }
};

const site = {
  entry: './site/common/js/site.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'site.js',
    publicPath: 'publicPath for site'
  }
};

module.exports = [common, mobile, site];
```

Вы можете иметь несколько конфигураций и экспортировать массив с ними.

Второй вариант это использование глобальной переменной `__webpack_public_path__`, вам нужно сеттить разное значение в 3х ваших файлах:

```
// common/index.js
__webpack_public_path__ = 'publicPath for common';

// common/mobile.js
__webpack_public_path__ = 'publicPath for mobile';

// common/js/site.js
__webpack_public_path__ = 'publicPath for site';
```

Не уверен насчет второго варианта, имея много входных точек, первый вариант будет точно без побочных эффектов.

Comment: сейчас попробую - спасибо )

Comment: если использовать первое решение, то в каждый миниконфиг нужно засетить основной конфиг с плагинами и остальными настройками ? Или его можно передать также в массиве ?

Comment: вы можете создать объект что-то типа `baseConfig` с лоадерами и плагинами и использовать деструктуризацию при экспорте - `module.exports = [{ ...mobile, ...baseConfig }, { ...site, ...baseConfig }]`